# Parallelize sorting algorithm using pyspark

Tags: python, sorting, parallel-processing, pyspark

Good morning, I have developed a simple merge-sort algorithm which I want to compare its performance when it is parallelized and not parallelized.

First, I am generating a list of numbers to sort and check how long it takes for the merge-sort to sort the list.

The next thing I want to do is passing the list of numbers into `sc.parallelize()` and converting the `list` to `RDD` followed by passing the merge-sort function into `mapPartitions()` and then `collect()`.

```
import random
import time
from pyspark import SparkContext

def execute_merge_sort(generated_list):
    start_time = time.time()
    sorted_list = merge_sort(generated_list)
    elapsed = time.time() - start_time
    print('Simple merge sort: %f sec' % elapsed)
    return sorted_list


def generate_list(length):
    N = length
    generated_list = [random.random() for num in range(N)]
    return generated_list

def merging(left_side, right_side):
    result = []
    i = j = 0
    while i < len(left_side) and j < len(right_side):
        if left_side[i] <= right_side[j]:
            result.append(left_side[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            result.append(right_side[j])
            j += 1
    if i == len(left_side):
        result.extend(right_side[j:])
    else:
        result.extend(left_side[i:])
    return result


def merge_sort(generated_list):
    if len(generated_list) <= 1:
        return generated_list
    middle_value = len(generated_list) // 2
    sorted_list = merging(merge_sort(generated_list[:middle_value]), merge_sort(generated_list[middle_value:]))
    return sorted_list


def is_sorted(num_array):
    for i in range(1, len(num_array)):
        if num_array[i] < num_array[i - 1]:
            return False
    return True

generate_list = generate_list(500000)

sorted_list = execute_merge_sort(generate_list)

sc = SparkContext()

rdd = sc.parallelize(generate_list).mapPartitions(execute_merge_sort).collect()
```

When I'm executing this `sc.parallelize(generate_list).mapPartitions(execute_merge_sort).collect()` I'm getting the following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-15-1b7974b4fa56>", line 7, in execute_merge_sort
  File "<ipython-input-15-1b7974b4fa56>", line 36, in merge_sort
TypeError: object of type 'itertools.chain' has no len()
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: change `len(generated_list)` to `len(list(generated_list))`

Comment: @OmG it now complains about line 39 `sorted_list = merging(merge_sort(generated_list[:middle_value]), merge_sort((generated_list[middle_value:])))` same error, any idea?

Comment: The same thing in `merging`. Change `left_side` and `right_side` to `list(left_side)` and `list(right_side)` respectively.

Comment: @OmG, it doesn't seem to change anything in the error.. can you try running the code and see if you can make it work? Thanks!

Comment: When I'm changing `mapPartitions` to `map`, it complains about `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable` on line 36 `(if len(list(generated_list)) <= 1:)`.

Comment: The error is true. In each pass in `map`, each float value would be computed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to solve the problem of `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`.

This can be solved by flattening the data using `flatMap(lambda x: x)` and calling `glom()` in order to wrap the list and make it executable by the function `execute_merge_sort`.
By executing the following line, the returned result is a list containing sorted lists.

```
sc.parallelize(random_list_of_lists).flatMap(lambda x: x).glom().mapPartitions(execute_merge_sort_rdd).collect()
```